# How to pass a parameter from a view to the controller with Ajax? Codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am just learning and I would like you to help me solve this problem: I have two views, in view 1 it shows me a list of users, when clicking on any of them you must open another view showing the information about that user in view 2 .
To do that in view 1 with js I capture the user's id and send it to the controller by ajax, and in the controller it sends it to the model and the model response returns to the controller and sends it to view2, to show only the information of the selected user, the question is that it does not work, could you help me, what am I doing wrong?
View 1: This is the paragraph where you click and capture the id and the ajax that sends that id to the controller.
View1

```
<p onclick="detalles('<?=$p->usuarioId?>');"> <?=$p->usuarioId?><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> <?php echo $p->user ?></p>

<script>
    function detalles(id=null){
        $ (document) .ready (function () {
                 console.log(id);
                 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data : {'id': id},
                    dataType:"html",
                    url: "usuarios_admin/ver",


                    success: function(result)
                    {

                    alert("good");
                  console.log("result",result);

                    }
                  });
            });
    }
</script>
```

Controller

```
    public function ver(){

         $id = $this->input->post("id");
          if($id != null) {
            $data = $this->PostUser->find($id);


            echo json_encode($data);
            $this->load->view('usuarios/vista2', $data);

          }
    }
```

model:

```
function find($id){
        $this->db->select();
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where($this->table_id, $id);

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->row();
    }
```

view2: 
here you must see the user data

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 lininfo">
                            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 sinpa">
                                <p class="colorp">Name:</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 sinpa">
                                <p class="colorpi"><?php $data['name'] ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean `it doesn't work`? Any errors occurred? Or you just didn't connect to DB and that why haven't any response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers, it came out.
I had to print on the view this way to see the data:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 lininfo">
                            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 sinpa">
                                <p class="colorp">Name :</p> 
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 sinpa">
                                <p class="colorpi"><?php echo $user->name ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

controller:

```
    public function ver(){

         $id = $this->input->post("id");
          if($id != null) {
            $data['user'] = $this->PostUser->find($id);

            $this->load->view('usuarios/vista2', $data);

          }
    }
```

ajax y view 1

```
<div class="hi">
<!-- here you would see the result of ajax -->
<div>

<script>
    function detalles(id=null){
        $ (document) .ready (function () {
                 console.log(id);
                 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data : {'id': id},
                    dataType:"html",
                    url: "usuarios_admin/ver",


                    success: function(result)
                    {

                 $('.hi').html(result);

                    }
                  });
            });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, i think there should be typo mistake

```
<p onclick="detalles('<?php echo $p->usuarioId ?>');"> <?php echo $p->usuarioId; ?>
<i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> <?php echo $p->user ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your 2nd view load after ajax call?
Have you print your return data in ajax success,because you define dataType:"html" in ajax but you return json data from controller.